# Generating TIFF with C# produces different files on different machines

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, tiff

I'm using the following code to test creating a Bitmap and saving it as a TIFF file. The code works fine, but on one of my computers the resulting TIFF produces a different MD5 hash than on a few other computers I have run the code on. The images appear identical on all machines, but for some reason the files are slightly different. Checking with a hex editor, it looks like the difference is only 4 bytes in the footer. I executed the code below using LinqPad. Here are the results:

```
CPU 1 (Windows 7) Hash:    7A-F7-F4-C5-1A-02-10-D5-FC-C9-40-A1-4F-18-D7-FE
Others (Windows 7/8) Hash: 0D-5D-23-58-2F-DE-D5-B3-CB-73-31-E1-37-CF-32-3C
```

Here is the test code:

```
void Main()
{
    using(var bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100))
    {
        using(var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 10, 10, 80, 80);
        }

        using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            SaveBitmapAsTIFFToStream(ms, bmp);

            ms.Position = 0;
            var provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            string hash = BitConverter.ToString(provider.ComputeHash(ms));

            Console.WriteLine(hash);
        }
    }
}

public static void SaveBitmapAsTIFFToStream(Stream stream, Bitmap b)
{
    b.Save(stream, FindEncoder(ImageFormat.Tiff), null);
}

private static ImageCodecInfo FindEncoder(ImageFormat fmt)
{
    return ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
            .FirstOrDefault(info1 => info1.FormatID.Equals(fmt.Guid));
}
```

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: Is it consistent for a single machine? Because the TIFF format [can contain a timestamp](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm). (Sorry if this is a stupid question :) )

Comment: @Rawling: Yes, the hashes are consistent. Thanks.

Comment: The .NET Framework version is the same on both machines?

Comment: @user3643376: Yes, the Framework versions are the same.

Comment: I'd like to suggest to try to inspect codec properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.drawing.imaging.imagecodecinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: for your info, i run your code and i get a different md5

Comment: like user3643376 said, put a breakpoint at the FindEncoder and check that you actually use the SAME codec. (what is returned by GetImageEncoders())

Comment: @Fredou: What OS are you using? Also, what version of .NET? I have the .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack and .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed on my test machines. And just out of curiousity, what language setting?

Comment: windows 7 64 bits, .net 4.5 and English Canada

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TIFF files can store large amounts of data and image information.

I was able to run your LinqPad program on two different machines and both returned the 0D-5D hash. 
I was then able to reproduce your MD5 hashes on a single machine by changing the font size settings found in Control Panel > Display. I got the 0D-5D hash when my fonts were set to the standard size, and I got the 7A-F7 hash when I set my fonts to 125%. I'm guessing that the font sizes on "CPU 1" are set to 125%, and that .NET must be encoding this information in the TIFF file.

Comment: FWIW, on a retina macbook and windows 8.1, I get the 7A-F7-...-FE hash. I am using non-standard font size in control panel.

Comment: Wow, really interesting. I was able to reproduce and get the 0D-5D hash when I switched my display fonts back to the standard setting. I wonder if there's any way to strip that info from the file, but in the meantime I think this answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: Good catch! Could it be simply the DPI setting in the TIFF that is changed, because of the font size change?

Answer (score 0):

Most .NET classes in `System.Drawing` namespace rely on unmanaged GDI+ runtime.

Each Windows OS since Windows XP ships with different version of GDI+. These versions often produce different results when decode or encode images. *Especially* TIFF images.